# Не обновляется SharedPreferences в Service

Tags: android, android-service, android-shared-preferences

В `Activity` и `Service` я создаю экземпляр на `SharedPreferences` вот так:

```
mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
```

`PREFERENCES_NAME` — константа.

Однако возникает проблема, когда я пытаюсь обновить в них данные (в `EditText` вводиться строка, я ее записываю): в `Activity` все обновляется, а в `Service` — нет, там остается старая информация! При чем после перезапуска `Service` все начинает работать!

---

Записываю я так (в `Activity`):

```
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(ID_KEY, userIdField.getText().toString());
    editor.putString(DOC_URL_KEY, docUrlField.getText().toString());
    editor.apply();
```

А читаю так (в `Service`):

```
    mSharedPreferences.getString(DOC_URL_KEY, "")
```

Вот объявление классов в манифесте:

```
   <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".DocumentHandleService"
        android:process="com.dugin.rostislav.reminderofwork.doc_handling_service" />
```

---

В чем проблема, почему так происходит и как это исправить?

Comment: Вызов `getSharedPreferences(...)` с флагом `Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS` не решит проблему? Правда оно `deprecated`. Подробнее можете [тут](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_MULTI_PROCESS) почитать.

Comment: @post_zeew, так он же устаревший, что уже говорит о неправильности его использования. Но, как ни странно, проблему решило...

Comment: Посмотрите ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В некоторых случаях проблему можно решить вызовом `getSharedPreferences(...)` с флагом `Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS`.

Но будьте внимательны, использовать `Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS` **не рекомендуется**, так как начиная с `API level 23` оно `deprecated`.

> This constant was deprecated in API level 23.
>   MODE_MULTI_PROCESS does not work reliably in some versions of Android, and furthermore does not provide any mechanism for reconciling concurrent modifications across processes. Applications should not attempt to use it. **Instead, they should use an explicit cross-process data management approach such as ContentProvider**.

**Правильным решением** проблемы будет написание своего механизма, который будет основываться на `ContentProvider`, или же можно использовать что-то готовое, вроде [этого](https://github.com/grandcentrix/tray).